# Differentiate $P$ in respect to $R$ and show that the power is maximum when $R=r$

Tags: calculus

Power development in a resistor $R$ by a battery of EMF $E$ and internal resistance $r$ is given by:

$$P=\frac{E^2R}{(R+r)^2}$$

Differentiate $P$ in respect to $R$ and show that the power is maximum when $R=r$

Comment: Looks like a homework problem (I saw the exact same problem in UPEC). What did you try to solve it? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem#Calculus-based_proof_for_purely_resistive_circuits

Comment: E²/R²+r²  so am I also supposed to differentiate the denominator and use the Quotient rule

Comment: Yes, the quotient rule is the right tool.

Answer (score 2):

We can write this equation as $$P=E^2R(R+r)^{-2}$$

We can then use the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) to differentiate it, with the two halves being $E^2R$ and $(R+r)^{-2}$

So, we have \begin{align}\frac d{dR}\left(E^2R(R+r)^{-2}\right)&=\frac d{dR}\left(E^2R\right)(R+r)^{-2}+(E^2R)\frac d{dR}(R+r)^{-2}\\\\
&=E^2(R+r)^{-2}+E^2R(-2)(R+r)^{-3}\\\\
&=\frac{E^2}{(R+r)^2}+\frac{-2E^2R}{(R+r)^3}\\\\
&=\frac{E^2(R+r)}{(R+r)^3}+\frac{-2E^2R}{(R+r)^3}\\\\
&=\frac{E^2R+E^2r-2E^2R}{(R+r)^3}\\\\
&=\frac{E^2r-E^2R}{(R+r)^3}\\\\
&=\frac{E^2(r-R)}{(R+r)^3}\end{align}

We can then find any critical pionts by setting $\frac{dP}{dR}=0$:

\begin{align}\frac{E^2(r-R)}{(R+r)^3}&=0\\
E^2(r-R)&=0\\
r-R&=0\\
r&=R\end{align}

And so we have a critical point when $r=R$.

We can check if this is a maximum or minimum by calculating the second derivative, using the product rule again (I leave the steps as an exercise for you):

$$\frac{d^2P}{dR^2}=-\frac {2E^2(2r-R)}{(R+r)^4}$$

We then set $r=R$:

\begin{align}-\frac {2E^2(2R-R)}{(R+R)^4}&=-\frac{2E^2R}{(2R)^4}\\
&=-\frac{2E^2R}{16R^4}\\
&=-\frac{E^2}{8R^3}\end{align}

We can see that this is negative, as $\cfrac{E^2}{8R^3}$ will be positive, as $E$ and $R$ are positive (you can check this if you know the values of $E$ and $R$). Therefore, this is a maximum of the function.